# How to install H2O driverless AI in a High Performance Computing?

Tags: h2o, hpc, driverless-ai

Is there any documentation on how to install/setup Driverless AI on a High-Performance Computing (HPC) environment, so I can request few nodes (with GPU each one) and have DAI take advantage of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the available installation instructions: http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/installing.html

here's the Linux in the Cloud section: http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/install/linux-in-the-cloud.html

Comment: Is there any conda env recipe that could be used?

Comment: @GuillermoEPonce-Campos are you referring the DAI python client package? https://anaconda.org/h2oai/repo and documentation here http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/python_install_client.html.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that.  I want to setup h2o.jar and DAI in an HPC system.  So far the h2o.jar is working in one node but still struggling to make it work with 4 nodes.  I've tried the -flatfile and -network parameters and still not able to make it work.  I did a question regarding this in the h2o gitter channel, are you in there?